# Providing default instance arguments for (recursive) extension in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, swift-extensions

I was having fun while practicing a Kata.
I wanted to implement one of the **functions** in my solution **as** an **extension** of `Int`, because I liked the idea of having pretty syntax. The function, in itself, looks like this:

```
func decomposed(_ n: Int) -> [Int] {
    if n > 10 {
      return n.decomposed(n / 10) + [n % 10] 
    } else {
      return [n]
    }
  }
```

Now, I've tried to implement it as an **extension**. Due to the fact that I would like to use it like `420.decomposed()`, I figured that I would need the **instance** as the **default argument**. I proceeded with:

```
extension Int {
  func decomposed(_ n: Int = self) -> [Int] {
    if n > 10 {
      return n.decomposed(n / 10) + [n % 10] 
    } else {
      return [n]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the part, however, in which it gets trickier. I'm being told by the compiler that `error: cannot find 'self' in scope`.

Having read about the methods [in the docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html#ID154), I've resorted to using `Int?` default argument. Now, the extension is implemented as:

```
extension Int {
  func decomposed(_ n: Int? = nil) -> [Int] {
    var _n = n ?? self
    if _n > 10 {
      return _n.decomposed(_n / 10) + [_n % 10] 
    } else {
      return [_n]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't like the look of the `_n`, though.
**I would love to use self as the default argument.** Is that possible? Or are we stuck with hackity hacks until the judgement day?

Comment: You're essentially just using an extension as a namespace to tuck a global function into. You're not taking advantage of the main purpose, which is the access to `self`, as shown by Abhinav below

Comment: OP might I know why has my answer not been accepted? It was added earlier and illustrates the same concept?

Comment: Rob's answer gives a clearer picture for this specific situation. His answer includes a code example that uses the function that was used in the question, providing a quicker visual help for the future visitors.
The remark about OOP paradigm is a bit broad - the usage of `self` in the original question points to recognizing the fact that it's OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `n` as a parameter, replace every use of `n` in the function with `self` (since that's what's being operated on), and convert the function syntax to the method syntax in the recursion:

```swift
extension Int {
    func decomposed() -> [Int] {
        if self > 10 {
            return (self / 10).decomposed() + [self % 10]
        } else {
            return [self]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrote a quick implementation to highlight the usage of extensions:

```swift
import Foundation

func main() {
  print(2.test()) // prints 2
  print(12.test()) // prints 3
  print(42.test()) // prints 6
}

extension Int {
  func test() -> Int {
    if self <= 10 {
      return self
    }
    return (self % 10) + (self/10).test();
  }
}

main()
```

You don't need to pass `self` as an argument, since that will not work. By default, `self` will be available for use inside the extension methods (since that follows the object oriented paradigm).

Answer (score 0):

In your function `decomposed`, you aren't using `self` and `n` anywhere together you can either make your decomposed method accept no parameter and use `self` from the function:

```swift
extension Int {
    func decomposed() -> [Int] {
        if self > 10 {
            return (self / 10).decomposed() + [self % 10]
        } else {
            return [self]
        }
    }
}
```

or if you plan to pass any parameter then you can just define a top level function instead of using extension:

```swift
func intDecomposed(_ n: Int) -> [Int] {
    if n > 10 {
        return n.decomposed(n / 10) + [n % 10]
    } else {
        return [n]
    }
}
```

You can use the above method inside the `decomposed` extension method providing self as parameter:

```swift
extension Int {
    func decomposed() -> [Int] {
        return intDecomposed(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: The first example is wrong, since the `self.decomposed`does not accept parameters and calling it recursively with parameters would probably cause the code to not compile at all. For the second remark - please read the question again. The whole purpose of this extension is not having to rely on an auxiliary function.

Comment: @JordanNiedzielski I have fixed the typo.